# A question about the comment for comment shell command

Tags: comments

When I read the comment help file, I found

> It is not possible to add a comment to a shell command ":!cmd" or to the
> ":map" command and a few others (mainly commands that expect expressions)
> that see the '"' as part of their argument: ...

What is it mean?

I add the line `":!ls"` to my vimrc file and nothing changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What it means you can't start a comment *after* the command; with `":!ls"` the `"` is *before* the command and comments out the entire line, and that's okay, but something like this won't work:

```
:!ls /  " List root directory
```

Because the `"` is interpreted as part of the shell command. It's the same with the :map commands; for example to create a map to add a quote at the end of the line we could do:

```
:nnoremap Q $a"<Esc>
```

But how will Vim know that `"` is what you intended to be part of the map or a comment? Vim solves this by just not interpreting comments for a few special commands.